# Mysqli - using select case but other data is not bound

Tags: php, sql, oop, mysqli

I'm using Mysqli OO to search the database for 2 specific values using the MySQL statement CASE. If both values are found then it will return the value 'true', if only one is found the value is 'false', if neither are found then the result is neither. Anyway I've got this working but my problem is I need it to also display the values that are related in the column.

```
$query = "SELECT 'userName','email','code',
CASE 
    WHEN (email=? AND code=?) THEN 'true'
    WHEN (email=?) THEN 'false'
    ELSE  'NONE'
END AS answer
FROM users WHERE email=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $email,$code, $email,$email);
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);
$code = $mysqli->real_escape_string($code);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($user,$email,$code,$answer);
$stmt->fetch();
print_r($stmt->fetch);
$stmt->store_result();
echo "User: ".$user." Email: ".$email." Code: ".$code." Answer: ".$answer;
```

Okay so when I run the code it should display as:

```
User: ryan Email: local@localhost Code: 12 Answer: true
```

But instead it displays it as:

```
User: userName Email: email Code: code Answer: true
```

So I think the error is more to do with the SQL side of it, but I'm stuck and would like some help. Thanks

Comment: Your code can never return `'neither'` for multiple reasons.

Comment: I meant 'true/false' as terms rather then a bool expression, and the neither expression was the first thing that came to my head :S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are selecting  string literals such as `'userName'` rather than the values contained in the columns.

To solve the problem either remove the quotes round your column names:

```
SELECT userName,email,code,...
```

Or use backticks (allowed, but only required if the column name is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)):

```
SELECT `userName`,`email`,`code`,...
```

Comment: Omg, I never realised I did that, such a simple mistake that has took me too long to figure out. Thanks very much for pointing that out :D